# Make a chatbot using slack

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

How did anaek created chat bots using slack for HR Tools and how much time will it take as a fresher to make a similar product?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the specific tools that you mentioned. But generally speaking, to create a chatbot, you would need to connect an API from Slack to your own API layer that handles the NLP side of it. So, if you're just starting out, your focus should be on creating an NLP algorithm that handles the types of questions that you want your bot to answer and converse with. You need to create code that both recognizes new inputs and understands how those inputs fit to everything else (i.e. an ongoing conversation). From there, you can create an API that you consume in any number of programs an you can practice with it (even in a terminal screen) for your own testing & algorithm training purposes. At that point, you should be able to integrate that into any number of platforms, slack being only one option.